# File will not be completely read byte by byte

Tags: c, file-io

Using a C program I am writing in Dev-C++, I want to read a binary file byte by byte. For some reason, the read stops at 261 bytes. Here is a simplified code which reproduces the bavior.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE *in_fp;
   char in_filename[25] = "data.raw";
   in_fp = fopen(in_filename,"r");
   if( in_fp == NULL ) {
      perror("Error while opening the input file.\n");
      system("PAUSE");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   int readcnt = 0;
   while (1) {
      unsigned char buffer;
      if (fread(&buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, in_fp) == 0) {
         printf("read eof after %d\n", readcnt);
         break;
      } else {
         printf("read = %d\n", buffer);
      }
      readcnt++;
   }


   fclose(in_fp);

   return 0;
}
```

The file data.raw has a size of 104 KiB.

The output of the program above ends with:

```
...
read = 255
read = 4
read = 204
read eof after 260
```

Using an hex-editor, I can find the bytes FF 04 CC , and there should be bytes followed after this, since the file is not at the end: FF 04 CC **1A 1F C5 8A** .

I also tried `fgetc()` and `feof()` and the behavior is the same.

Why does the reading stops at offset 260?

Comment: If you're on windows and the file is in text mode, `1A` == ctrl+Z, i.e. EOF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to open your file in ["binary mode"](http://c-faq.com/stdio/textvsbinary.html):

```
fopen(in_filename, "rb");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this fast answer! This solved the problem. I was searching all the time at the wrong location.

Comment: @rinntech Mentioning `dev-c++` immediately triggered "oh right, windows" :-)